# How to understand count number sqlite rows?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsdictionary

I have a sqlite DB in a Document Folder application. I store data from NSDictionary in sqlite DB. I want how to understand how many rows there are in the sqlite database and put it in NSString variable.

This is my code to store data in sqlite (in Document Folder):

```
#define DatabaseName @"data.sqlite"
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //NSString *rowNumber = I dont know how to Obtain number of rows...
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *idd = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"122",@"234",@"453", nil];
    NSArray *name = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"janatan",@"fred",@"john", nil];
    NSArray *age = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"23",@"35",@"12", nil];
    NSArray *sex = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"male",@"male",@"male", nil];
    NSString *query2  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from table1 where name = 'john'"];
    NSLog(@"query : %@",query2);
    BOOL recordExist = [self recordExistOrNot:query2];
    if (!recordExist) {
        for (int i = 0; i < [idd count]; i++) {
            NSString * a = [idd objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString * b = [name objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString * c = [age objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString * d = [sex objectAtIndex:i];
            NSDictionary * dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:a,@"id",b,@"name",c,@"age",d,@"sex", nil];
            NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into table1 (id,name,age,sex) values('%@','%@','%@','%@')",[dic objectForKey:@"id"],[dic objectForKey:@"name"],[dic objectForKey:@"age"],[dic objectForKey:@"sex"]];
            NSLog(@"%@",query);
            [self executeQuery:query];
        }
    }
}
-(NSString *) dataFilePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    //NSLog(@"PATH %@",[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:DatabaseName]);
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:DatabaseName];
}
/*==================================================================
 METHOD FOR CHECKING WHETHER RECORD EXISTS OR NOT IN DATABASE
 ==================================================================*/
-(BOOL)recordExistOrNot:(NSString *)query{
    BOOL recordExist=NO;
    if(sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK) {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
                recordExist=YES;
            } else {
                //////NSLog(@"%s,",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(database);
        }
    }
    return recordExist;
}
/*==================================================================
 METHOD FOR INSERTING DATA IN DATABASE
 ==================================================================*/
-(void)executeQuery:(NSString *)query {
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if(sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"query Statement Not Compiled");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Data not Opened");
    }
}
@end
```

You guess top NSArray has how many values (not four).

Comment: [fetchedArray count] will give you count, isn't it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to use this one

Execute this query

```
select count(*) from table_name;

- (int) getNumberOfRecord
{
    int count = 0;
    if (sqlite3_open([self.dataBasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char* sqlStatement = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1";
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK )
        {
            //Loop through all the returned rows (should be just one)
            while( sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW )
            {
                count = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog( @"Failed from sqlite3_prepare_v2. Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
        }

        // Finalize and close database.
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }

    return count;
}
```

i hope its help u.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 Load Database
 **/
func loadDatabase() {
    let fileUrl = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("yourdatabase.sqlite")

    if(sqlite3_open(fileUrl.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
        print("Error opening database")
        createAlert(title: "Information", message: "Error opening database")
        return
    } else {
        print("Everything Look Great")
    }

}    

/**
 * Count Trip New
 *
 * @return
 */
func getCountTripNew() -> Int{
    loadDatabase()

    var count : Int = 0
    //this is your select query
    let queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trip "

    //statement pointer
    var stmt:OpaquePointer?

    //preparing the query
    if sqlite3_prepare(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error preparing count trip: \(errmsg)")
        return 0
    }

    //traversing through all the records
    while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
        count = Int(sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0))

    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt)
    sqlite3_close(self.db)

    return count
}
```